# Can we schedule a apex class at a time in different time zones

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

We have a batch class to updates events dates.
But all the users are not in same time zone.Some users are in Uk,Some are in USA,Some are in India..etc

My batch class will run every day at 1 am of users timezone.

Can we execute my batch class in different time zones from scheduler class.
Can any one guide the best thoughts to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to calculate the differences manually if you need to run it in a specific time zone. The API for this feature is always designed to use the user's current time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
You mean to say,I have to select the best time to considering all the time zones to schedule this batch?